# Which config.ini?

Tags: cleos

I am supposed to alter the config.ini  (not using the Docker, but a compiled version)

However, I have these:

```
eos/build/config.ini
eos/Docker/config.ini
eos/build/staging/etc/eosio/node_00/config.ini
eos/build/staging/etc/eosio/node_01/config.ini
eos/build/staging/etc/eosio/node_02/config.ini
eos/build/staging/etc/eosio/node_03/config.ini
eos/build/staging/etc/eosio/node_bios/config.ini
```

Which one should I be adjusting?

Comment: Please clarify what do you want to change?

Comment: config.ini to add a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the config and data directory to use with the following parameter when starting nodeos:

```
./eos/build/programs/nodeos/nodeos --data-dir /home/USER/path-to-data-dir --config-dir /home/USER/path-to-config-dir
```

Comment: And if I don't specify, which config.ini is a default one?  (I need to know before accepting the answer).

Comment: @DisplayName Normally, if you want to run with a custom config.ini, you would copy it to a new location, such as your data directory, and modify it there.  For example, if you start the chain and specify a data dir, it will write a config.ini into the data dir.  You can then stop the chain, modify the config.ini to enable your needed plugin, and then restart the chain.